# ASP.NET AJAX PageLoad event not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I inherited some code that uses ASP.NET AJAX pageLoad client side event.
The code runs fine and the method is called when the page is opened in the server in an URL such as http://localhost/IISApp/page.aspx, but when I open it in the server with URL http://ServerName/IISApp/page.aspx, the pageLoad is not called.

Any idea on what may be causing the behavior? This happens in Firefox and IE.

Update:
The pageLoad is in a separate file, and is declared as

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
   ....
}
```

This file is included in the master page as:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/functions.js" />
```

It's running is IIS7, there are no special configurations in IIS for when a user hits the site with server name or localhost. If I run it from VS 2010 (Cassini web server), the method is also not being called.

Thx in advance

Comment: Please, post the code to see it.

Comment: Have you installed the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx) on the server?

Comment: what version of iis ?, probably is not setup the same for this names you enter.

Comment: I think you're facing the similar issue posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543332/pageload-not-firing-in-a-dynamically-loaded-page-using-net-4-0-works-fine-on)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a script manager to your aspx page,
or you can add the following script to the page head

```
document.body.onload=pageLoad;
```

regards