# pageLoad() not firing in a dynamically loaded page using .NET 4.0 (Works fine on 3.5)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a simple aspx page with a link to load another aspx page on right div (using JQuery load), like that:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPage() {
            $('#myRightdiv').load('Test.aspx', function () {});
        }
    </script>

 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Load ..." OnClientClick="loadPage(); return false;" />
 <div id="myRightdiv"></div>
 </form>
```

In my Test.aspx I have a pageLoad like that:

```
<%@ Page Title="Test" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {          
       alert("pageloaded");
    }        
  </script> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

That works fine on ASP .NET 3.5 .... But using .NET 4.0 the pageLoad is not fired!

Any idea or workaround?

Thanks

Comment: The generated HTML source code (instead of the ASP.net source code) would be more useful (since this is a JavaScript problem).

Comment: Which `pageLoad` is not fired? The one in the main page or the one in Test.aspx?

Comment: Test.aspx pageLoad()... It works fine using .NET 3.5... That pageLoad is a ASP .NET Ajax shortcut (encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

Comment: From what I can see in the source code of Test.aspx, nothing is triggering the `pageLoad` function. For instance, one method would be `<body onload="pageLoad()">`, or an ASP.net equivalent, but you don't seem to define such an attribute. Compare the source code in 3.5 and 4.0 and check if some "onload" attribute exists in 3.5.

Comment: I dont need to define it... As I said, Its a .NET shortcut and works fine with .NET 3.5... Something changed in .NET 4.0...

Comment: Post the generated HTML source code of Test.aspx. (Just load Test.aspx in a separate browser tab, right click on it, and choose "View source"). By examining the generated source code, we'll be able to tell if the `pageLoad` function is called properly.

Comment: Loading Test.aspx directly on browser fired pageLoad() in 4.0 and 3.5 fine!  The problem happens only when loading a aspx dynamically...

Comment: I'm guessing that the ASP.net engine automatically appends a JavaScript script file to the web-page. This built-in script is then binding the `pageLoad` function to the "onload" event of the web-page. Now, if this is true, the issue is probably with jQuery's `load()` function since it appends the `<script>` elements from Test.aspx to the currently loaded page. As a consequence, the global variables of Test.aspx are overwriting the existing global variables from the main page. These name collisions could be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The special `pageLoad` function is called when the Microsoft Ajax Library has finished initializing the `Sys.Application` object. Unfortunately, this initialization code was drastically rewritten in ASP.NET 4.0 (details below), and now, in standards-compliant browsers, `Sys.Application` doesn't get initialized at all when a page is loaded by the jQuery `load` function. Fortunately, there's a simple workaround: initialize `Sys.Application` yourself:

```
$('#myRightdiv').load('Test.aspx', function () { Sys.Application.initialize(); });
```

I tested this fix in IE9 (Standards mode), Firefox, and Chrome.

To get your example to work in IE9 (Quirks mode), you also need to move your `pageLoad` function up into the `<head>`.

### What Changed Between ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.0

In ASP.NET 3.5, the `<asp:ScriptManager>` control inserts a call to `Sys.Application.initialize()` right before the `</form>` tag. When jQuery loads Test.aspx, it executes each `<script>` in sequence, so your `pageLoad` is defined before `Sys.Application.initialize()` calls it, and everything works.

In ASP.NET 4.0, the `<asp:ScriptManager>` control no longer inserts that bit of JavaScript. Instead:

- In browsers that support `document.addEventListener` [such as IE9 (Standards mode), Firefox, and Chrome], the `Sys.Application` constructor adds a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener that calls `Sys.Application.initialize()`. But `DOMContentLoaded` was already raised when the browser finished loading the *current* page (Default.aspx). Loading Test.aspx via an AJAX request won't cause the browser to re-raise `DOMContentLoaded`.
- In browsers that support `document.attachEvent` but not `document.addEventListener` [such as IE9 (Quirks mode)], the `Sys.Application` constructor calls `Sys.Application.initialize()` if the browser has finished loading the current page (which it has, since the current page is Default.aspx). In this case, you need to define your `pageLoad` function *before* MicrosoftAjax.js is included; a good place is the `<head>`.

Comment: Great!so catch was to call intialize() and move pageLoad function to the <head> so it will work with IE 9 standard mode and quirks mode. Works like a charm! Learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you are calling your target page which was not fully loaded then you will call pageload method it will be not applied on it so you have to call after page will be fully loaded

so you can do some simple solution as below  in Test.aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {          
       alert("pageloaded");
    }        

    pageLoad(); //invoke pageLoad immediately
  </script>
```

the other reason related to 3.5 and 4.0 i think some processing time higher in 4.0 for loading scriptmanager.

Comment: Thanks,but If I call it manually I´ll lost the pageLoad meaning and will not resolve my problem (I need get a telerik component that is only available on pageLoad)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Sys.Application.add_load(handler) instead which is raised before the pageLoad, for more info check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829) out.

It seems nothing has changed for pageLoad as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb386417.aspx) in documentation. If you are not performing any operation on partial postback then you can use window.onload as well.

If you're just checking whether response has received successfully, you can use callback function of [Jquery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Sys.Application.add_load does no work as well... You can easily replicate the problem it you wish...

Comment: You're right, it is not working with .net 4.0 but with .net 3.5 it works without any issue. However with .net 4.0 if I change IE browser mode from IE9 to IE8 and if I continue, it displays message, weird